# In AppleScript, how to open a URL location that contains a hash (#)?

Tags: macos, applescript, encoding, url

I have a workflow written in Alfred that when opening a URL location in AppleScript, the URL will be `urlencoded()` which effectively breaks:

```
open location "https://example.com/#hello" & selectedText
```

will open the URL `https://example.com/%23hello`.

The `%23` should really stay `#`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Try removing the `/` before the `#` character, or supply the name of the webpage between `/` and `#` character.

Comment: Nimesch, that helps me a lot right now! Not sure if it solves the problem in a generic way though. If you want, please phrase it as an answer so I can vote it up.

Comment: Which browser are you using?  I've just tested with Safari, Chrome, and Firefox and none give a problem opening a URL with an anchor (#).

Comment: I'm running this from Alfred as a custom workflow, opening in Safari.

Comment: It's very important you add the relevant details.  So...it's *Alfred* that's doing this, not macOS or AppleScript per se.  Can you open the URL properly via AppleScript only?  This will confirm if it's an Alfred issue or a larger system wide issue on your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Alfred is encoding (UTF8) the URL.

[image]

Disable it and it will work.

Comment: I do not use Alfred but am curious to know if that's a global setting or a per workflow setting?

Comment: @user3439894 - That a "per query" setting.  I believe it defaults to UTF8

Comment: Ah... a "per query" setting, makes sense. +1 for the answer to the OP.